# deadlock when SQL Server transaction log ever-increase?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, deadlock

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I have tried that if I set SQL Server transaction log to ever increase for the related database (with no backup settings), then a single delete statement of this stored procedure will cause deadlock if executed by multiple threads at the same time? Any ideas why?

For the delete statement, Param1 is a column of table FooTable, Param1 is a foreign key of another table (refers to another primary key clustered index column of the other table). There is no index on Param1 itself for table FooTable. FooTable has another column which is used as clustered primary key, but not Param1 column.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FooProc]    
(  
 @Param1 int 
 ,@Param2 int  
 ,@Param3 int  
)    
AS    

DELETE FooTable WHERE  Param1 = @Param1     

INSERT INTO FooTable    
 (  
 Param1  
 ,Param2  
 ,Param3  
  )    
 VALUES    
 (  
 @Param1  
 ,@Param2  
 ,@Param3  
  )    

DECLARE @ID bigint    
 SET @ID = ISNULL(@@Identity,-1)    
 IF @ID > 0    
 BEGIN    
      SELECT IdentityStr FROM FooTable WHERE ID = @ID 
 END
```

Comment: Is it really a deadlock (with one thread being aborted as a deadlock victim), or is it just a "delay" until the first thread finishes??

Comment: George, this is the third time you ask about the same deadlock and never provided the deadlock info. Without the deadlock info, you are wasting your time. Attach Profiler, monitor for the Deadlock Graph Event Class *only*, wait for deadlock to occur, attach the saved .xdl to your post.

Comment: @Marc, it is deadlock. I catch it in log. Any relationship between transaction log ever-increase and deadlock?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "ever-increase" log - the transaction log by design is ever increasing, really..... - so I don't know if that would have any effect on deadlocks - but I'd guess: no, this has no influence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should always create an index on the column that has FOREIGN KEY constraint. Otherwise, deadlock is very likely to happen (because the server has to lock the whole dependent table to ensure that constraint)

Comment: Any ideas why deadlock happens if transaction log ever-increase?

Comment: No... Transaction log completes after SQL server encounters an open transaction.